# Меню в мобильной версии больше чем шапка

Tags: html, css

Помогите плиз.
Если менять ширину экрана, то появиться меню бургер.
Суть в том, что сама менюха больше шапки и это видно.
Подскажите плиз как решить эту проблемку.)

Также пользуясь случаем прошу, посоветуйте как научиться верстать очень качественно, быстро и правильно.)

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 background: #F2F2F2;
}
a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}
.container{
 max-width: 1202px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 20px;
}
.wrapper{
 min-height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}
/*header*/
.header{
 background: #171641;
}
.menu{
 display: flex;
 margin: 0;
}
.menu-item{
 list-style: none;
}
.menu-item a{
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-left: 40px;
 transition: 0.2s ease;
}
.menu-item a:hover{
 opacity: 0.6;
}
.nav{
 padding: 16px 0; 
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
}
.logo{
 width: 56px;
 height: 56px;
 border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
 border-radius: 100%;
}
.menu__btn{
 color: white;
 font-size: 40px;
 display: none;
}
/*/header*/

/*main*/
.main__container{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
 padding-bottom: 244px;
 padding-top: 38px;
}
.main__item{
 background: #C4C4C4;
 height: 286px;
 margin-bottom: 38px;
}
.main__item:first-child{
 width: 43.4276206323%;
}
.main__item:nth-child(2){
 width: 25.7903494176%;
}
.main__item:nth-child(3){
 width: 25.7903494176%;
}
.main__item:nth-child(4){
 width: 30.282861896838604%;
}
.main__item:nth-child(5){
 width: 48.58569051580699%;
}
.main__item:last-child{
 width: 15.391014975041598%;
}
/*/main*/

/*footer*/
.footer{
 background: #171641;
 height: 92px;
}
/*/footer*/

/*media*/
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
 .menu__btn{
  display: block;
 }
 .nav{
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 .menu{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
        background: #171641;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 90px;
 }
 .menu-item{
  margin-bottom: 40px;
 }
 .menu-item a{
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-left: 0;
 }
}
/*/media*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>adaptive</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <!-- header -->
  <header class="header">
   <div class="container">
    <nav class="nav">
     <div class="logo"></div>
     <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
     </ul>
     <div class="menu__btn"><a href="#">&#8801;</a></div>
    </nav>
   </div>
  </header>
  <!-- /header -->

  <!-- main -->
  <main class="main">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="main__container">
     <div class="main__item"></div>
     <div class="main__item"></div>
     <div class="main__item"></div>
     <div class="main__item"></div>
     <div class="main__item"></div>
     <div class="main__item"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </main>
  <!-- /main -->

  <!-- footer -->
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
  <!-- /footer -->
 </div>
 
 <script>
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, проблема в том, что в мобильной версии под пунктами меню слишком много свободного места (?)

Убирайте из **@media screen and (max-width: 768px)** параметр **height: 100%;** и это решает проблему.

Если я понял неверно, то подробнее опишите, чего хотите добиться.